# What is nginx's $request_time and why is it a lot more than php-fpm execution time?

Tags: nginx, php

**Background**: It is the objective of my project is to create a very fast responding website. There are only very few pages, many of them are simply 302 redirects.

In **Nginx**, I'm logging [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format) `$request_time`.

In **PHP**, I'm logging the `microtime` of the start of the request and just before it exits.

**php-fpm** (php 5.3.27) and **nginx** (1.4.4) run on the same machine, there is no database (just writing to a Beanstalkd queue), there are no complicated **nginx** configurations.

**Problem**: There is a massive discrepancy between the PHP execution time and Nginx's $request_time. The $request_time is generally 0.5 seconds but during some hours it's more like **3 seconds** on average. PHP's execution time is always between 0.008 seconds and 0.02 seconds (using [PhalconPHP](http://phalconphp.com/)).

**Question**: Why could there be such a big discrepancy? Perhaps I don't fully understand what `$request_time` is, or maybe my webservers have some problematic configuration? I'd be happy to provide more information about the environment.

Answer (score 2):

`$request_time` is the time from the first byte sent, to the time everything is closed up and logging has been completed.  If you look at your nginx logs and the microtime you are logging, how close are they in terms of starting times?  For the ones where  the request_time was closer to 3 seconds, and the php execution time was say 0.02 seconds, if you extrapolate the request start time and compare that to the microtime inside php, are they close, or did nginx need to wait a second or 2 (perhaps for a php process to free up, etc..).   It would probably be interesting to also log the `$upstream_response_time`  to see how that compares.

Comment: Seems like the end time of PHP corresponds with the time in the nginx access log. Would this imply that Nginx had to wait for a PHP-FPM process to free up? There are currently 60 PHP-FPM workers running concurrently. Would changing this number potentially solve the problem? The server load is very low (and is actively monitored) so that shouldn't be the problem.

From the **Nginx access log**:
Time: [07/Dec/2013:05:30:09 -0800]
$request_time: 10.270 seconds

From the **php file logs**:
Start of index: 2013-12-07 05:29:59.436702
Sent redirect header, about to exit: 2013-12-07 05:30:09.490813

Comment: IN looking at that log, If I am reading it correctly. It looks like it took 10 seconds, so nginx got the request at 5:20:09, but php didn't see the request to 5:29, so that looks like for some reason nginx waited 9.5 seconds to hand it off to php, So it could be resource contention. How many nginx workers do you have, how many concurrent connections do you have (to the server, not php-fpm runninG)  And yes the End time should match.  it is the start time we are interested in,  How long did nginx wait to have to hand the connection to php.

Comment: There are 4 nginx master processes. "netstat -nap | grep 80 | grep ESTAB | wc -l" tells me around 150. How do I figure out what's stopping nginx from handing the request to php-fpm? Is php-fpm telling nginx that it's busy (can this happen?), could nginx be too busy handling other requests that it doesn't pass this one off to php-fpm? Should I add some more nginx workers? I've been googling for many days but have yet to find a hint to what may be going on.

Comment: I'm wondering why there doesn't seem to be any decent documentation related to this anywhere. I'd appreciate some good sources for your answers as well, if possible.

Comment: I'd like to award the bounty to you Doon, but I'd need more sources and if you could also answer hdeh's comments as well.

Comment: I am not really sure how to debug it further I sure you have seen (http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/nginx-performance) and perhaps (http://www.zend.com/en/products/server/nginx-performance)  Not that they are going to be much help.  Is this server doing anything else (mixed workload, could the nginx workers all bet IO bound, and stucking waiting on that. I wonder if tcpdumping the connection between nginx and php-fpm would be useful, to watch the interaction there.